# Looping through a list using PushButton - PyQt5

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I am currently trying to loop through a predefined list, changing `label_1` to the string at each index when `pushButton_1` is clicked.

I think I have to define the label within a loop (as shown below) and then increase the count using a function connected to the pushbutton, but I have been unsuccessful so far.

Another thought of mine is to 'listen' for the click of the button, and then only increase the index once that condition is met - this seems more intuitive to me, but I am unsure of how to do this.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

list_1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']

def loop(count_value):
    return count_value + 1

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        MainWindow.setWindowTitle('List Looper')
        MainWindow.resize(540, 465)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))

        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 141, 31))
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(loop)
        self.pushButton_1.setText('Next Index')

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 281, 16))

        count = 0
        while count < len(list_1):
            self.label_1.setText(list_1[count])

            # Run the loop() function upon button click to increase the count.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have tried to find similar problems, but many seem to to deal with replacing widget elements, and that is not what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second method is correct but you have to make the counter an attribute of the class and increase it each time the method associated with the button's clicked signal is invoked:

```py
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("List Looper")
        MainWindow.resize(540, 465)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))

        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 141, 31))
        self.pushButton_1.setText("Next Index")

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 281, 16))

        self.counter = 0

        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

    def handle_clicked(self):
        if self.counter < len(list_1):
            self.label_1.setText(list_1[self.counter])
            self.counter += 1
```